# Singleton design pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am following this link https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/ to understand design patterns in Javascript I understood constructor pattern , module pattern and module revealing pattern , now in Singleton pattern I have two doubts which are following :

1) I know c++ and I am learning JavaScript now, so I understand singleton pattern allows you only one instance of the class but in this book it's mentioned   "In JavaScript, Singletons serve as a shared resource namespace which isolate implementation code from the global namespace so as to provide a single point of access for functions." What does it mean ???

2)

```
var mySingleton = (function () {

// Instance stores a reference to the Singleton
var instance;

function init() {

// Singleton

// Private methods and variables
function privateMethod(){
    console.log( "I am private" );
}

var privateVariable = "Im also private";

var privateRandomNumber = Math.random();

return {

  // Public methods and variables
  publicMethod: function () {
    console.log( "The public can see me!" );
  },

  publicProperty: "I am also public",

  getRandomNumber: function() {
    return privateRandomNumber;
  }

};

};

return {

// Get the Singleton instance if one exists
// or create one if it doesn't
getInstance: function () {

  if ( !instance ) {
    instance = init();
  }

  return instance;
}

};

})();

var singleA = mySingleton.getInstance();
var singleB = mySingleton.getInstance();
```

My doubt is when we call mySingleton.getInstance(); won't be the value "instance" undefined again, as it is a local variable and everytime we call the getInstance method it should set the instance value as undefined and hence 
        if ( !instance )
should pass always and give a new instance but I don'y understand how it's working here. Kindly explain.

Comment: No, `var instance` defined in "outer" scope. (not in scope of `getInstance` function)

Comment: My advice is to look up what closures are in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks point 2 is clear now... but what about point no 1 ? Kindly explain ...

Comment: @user3651606 does the book suggest that in javascript the singleton is used differently than in other languages? That text sortof just defines what a singleton is.

Answer (score 1):

**var mySingleton** is a IIFE function and this returns you an object (or in module revealing pattern term, exposes property of getInstance)

Every time **mySingleton** is referred in the code, the content inside it executes every time. Hence resetting instance variable. Note, **init** method also returns an object with 3 properties **indicating that these are exposable too (can be made public and even the private variables can be made public by processing them in a public function. Pretty much the C++/Java concepts)**.

In the end, we use this init() and tag it to getInstance

Hence when I do 
var singleA = mySingleton.getInstance();
var singleB = mySingleton.getInstance();

I can access the (selectively)"exposed" properties singleA.publicMethod()

Flow: **singleA** [refers to] **getInstance()** [exposed through] **mySingleton** [and] **getInstance()** [refers to] **init()** [which exposes] **publicMethod**, **publicProperty** and **getRandomNumber** [which indirectly gives you access to] **privateRandomNumber**

**Doubt #1**
Serve as a shared resource namespace and hide code implementation.
It is sharing the private properties and methods of init method globally whilst you are in a namespace 1 level above init.

Private methods are hidden and not exposed.

**Doubt #2**
Every time mySingleton is referred, instance is re-declared.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

1) This means that only variable `var mySingleton` is now accessible from global namespace. It exposes single public method `getInstance` which returns one and only one instance of a class (code responsible for managing private reference to this instance is hidden from outside scope).

2) No, `var instance` is defined in "outer" scope. (not in scope of `getInstance` function)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript Object is a reference data type which means the instance returned here is same.

```
var singleA = mySingleton.getInstance();
var singleB = mySingleton.getInstance();

singleA === singleB // > true
```

and the fact that we are able to access the instance variable in getInstance function of mySingleton is due to closure's